# Intel Raid and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drivers, raid

I have an ASUS P8P67 REV 3.1 board with an Intel i5-2500K processor.

I have two disks for my data which are joined in a Raid 1 configuration, which is builtin by the chipset.

I would now like to change my disks because I think they are in the process of giving up now. I switched from Windows 7 to Windows 10 a while back and during the upgrade the management software for the raid disappeared. My question is, can I install Intel RST driver (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27147/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-?product=55005) without ill effect (probably the 14.8.0 version) or am I doomed if I do that and something doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you if that would crash your system.
I guess a failsafe way to test it would be to physically remove one drive from the system and use it as backup if anything goes wrong.
Then just plug in your new drives and migrate your data.